# SQL - Counting months passed by a Person Indicator

Tags: sql, sql-server, vertica

I'm trying to count the number of months that have passed based on ID, it's possible that for some records the months will not increase by 1 each time (i.e. someone could have a record for `1/1/13` and `3/1/13` but not `2/1/13`) however I only want a count of the records in my table. So missing months don't matter.

An example table would be: (notice the missing month and it's irrelevancy).

```
DATE        ID  Months Passed
----------- --- --------------
2013-11-01  105 1
2013-12-01  105 2
2014-02-01  105 3
2014-03-01  105 4
```

Essentially an Excel `COUNTIFS`in SQL, which I've written:

```
=COUNTIFS(IDColumn, ID, MonthColumn, "<=" & Month)
```

Does anyone know of a way to generate the desired column using SQL?

Comment: How about ROW_NUMBER? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Try ROW_NUMBER(). If you just want the "Months Passed" column to increase by 1 each time, and for each ID, that will do the trick.

```
SELECT
Date,
Id,
Indicator,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Date) AS RowNum
FROM YourTable
WHERE Indicator = 'YES'

UNION

SELECT
Date,
Id,
Indicator,
0 AS RowNum
FROM YourTable
WHERE Indicator = 'NO'
```

Comment: Excellent! That worked great. To build off of my question, there is an additional column that I omitted simply because I thought if this question was answered then the other would be easily solved but I'm seeing now that's not the case. 

The column in question is a "Yes/No" indicator, and the end-game for this query is to show their growing record. How would I go about counting the YES values based on ID and Month in a growing fashion as well? The added "I only want to count YES values" seems to put a wrench into the ROW_NUMBER() command. However it did work great for the Months Passed.

Comment: Good question... You're right that adding another column throws a wrench in things. It's a little bit of a hack, but you can UNION two queries. One will count, using the query above WHERE Yes/No = "YES". Then UNION WHERE Yes/No = "NO" and just use 0 as your row number... Let me know if that doesn't work for you.

Comment: Updated original answer with query changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ben this worked great. I appreciate you taking the time to write it out; I was having trouble getting the output to be correct.

Comment: Great, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You could more simply count rows grouped by month (more complex if you have count months in different years separately):

```
SELECT COUNT(derived.monthVal) 
FROM (SELECT MONTH(<your date field>) AS monthVal 
      FROM [your table] 
      WHERE [Your ID Column] = <the id>
      GROUP BY MONTH(<your date field>)) AS derived;
```